# How to get current function object in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the current function I'm in?

I'm looking for the actual function object, not the function name.

```
    def foo(x,y):
        foo_again = <GET_CURRENT_FUNCTION>
        if foo_again == foo:
            print ("YES they are equal!")
```

I assume I could do that in Python inspect module, but I can't seem to find it.

EDIT
The reason I want that is I want to print out the arguments to my function. And I can do that with inspect. Like this

```
   def func(x,y):
       for a in inspect.getfullargspec(func).args:
           print (a, locals()[a])
```

This works, but I don't want to have to manually write the function name. Instead, I want to do

```
   def func(x,y):
       for a in inspect.getfullargspec(<GET_CURRENT_FUNCTION>).args:
           print (a, locals()[a])
```

Comment: i updated question

Comment: What's so bad about writing the function name?

Comment: i plan to copy and paste these 2 lines of code to all functions that i want to see arguments for. so i don't want to change the function name every time i need to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't a decorator be better then? And see http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

from [inspect.stack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) you can get the function's name.

Here is a workaround that might not be optimal but it gives your expected results.

```
def foo(x,y): 
    this_function = inspect.stack()[0].function 
    for a in inspect.getfullargspec( eval(this_function) ).args: 
        print(a, locals()[a]) 
    print(this_function)
```

Then

```
foo('a','b')
>>>
    x a
    y b
    foo
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is by using a decorator.  Here's an example:

```
def passFunction(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(func,*args, **kwarsgs)
    return new_func

@passFunction
def foo(f, x, y):
    ...

foo(x,y)
```